# Non-constant wavelength of particles

Tags: particle-physics, wavelength, redshift

Is it possible for a particle's wavelength to change with respect to time? I'm thinking of a massless particle like a photon, but as it evolves through time its wavelength changes. I'm aware photons wavelengths do change from the expansion of spacetime, but I'm thinking on a smaller scale.

EDIT
Is it possible to have a particle that has its wave length change in time? So imagine a particle that is created with a wave length of say 500nm then it decays to infinity or something as it evolves through time.

Answer (score 0):

The wavelength of a photon does not mean a single  photon is spread in space. At our level of experiments and theories photons and the other [elementary particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle) are point particles at (x,y,z) at time t, described by [four vectors,](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) whose "length" gives the invariant mass of the particle.

[image: fourv]

[image: invmass]

In the case of photons, the invariant mass is zero, but energy and momentum are there, and the energy is given by $hν$  where $ν$ is the frequency of light that can be produced by accumulating photons of such energy, see [this simple experiment](https://www.sps.ch/artikel/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/) to get some intuition on how photons behave.

Now four vectors transform from kinematic frame to kinematic frame according to the Lorentz transformations, and depending on the frame the energy of the photon can be larger or smaller.

So the answer  is that the *energy* of the photons changes according to the kinematic  frame it is observed  in, and thus the [wavelength](https://www.everythingrf.com/rf-calculators/wavelength-to-frequency) of the possible light beam constructed of such energy photons would change .

Comment: Your answer shows the wavelength isn't invariant, not that it isn't conserved.

Comment: @J.G. The question is about constancy, not conservation. A given photon can have different frequency depending on the inertial frame it is observed. The wavelength of the possible classical EM wave to be built up by a multitude of such energy photons has a wavelength.

Comment: The first sentence of the question makes clear "constant" meant time-dependent, which is its usual meaning.

Comment: @J.G. It is not constant between inertial frames , but Lorenhttp://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/ltrans.htmltz transformation dependent. To go from one inertial frame to another time is needed for the measurement/observation. the t in the formulas is "time"

Comment: Sorry, I can't find an edit of your hyperlink that works for me.

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/ltrans.html  , sorry.

Comment: I know time appears in these transformations, but this question clearly wasn't looking for wavelength varying by reference frame.

Answer (score 0):

The photon wavelength may vary for a photon propagating in a non-uniform medium - with variable $n(\vec{r})$, the frequency being constant.

Comment: In mainstream physics, the photon does not have a wavelength, it is the classical electromagnetic wave  that has a wavelength . The photon is a point particle and this hypothesis is consistent with experiments, as the one I have linked  in the answer with single photons.

Comment: @annav: You forgot a wave-particle dualism in QM. In particular, we write a wave equation for wave functions.